# R: Recursive sum of functions of x

Tags: r

I would like to program a sum of k functions of x depending upon a index i=1,...k, and also depending on the a point x0 (it looks a bit like a Taylor formula). However, the following code produces the error message:

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
>
> Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

I would appreciate if somebody could help to improve on it:

```
cum_f <- function(x, x0, k){
  i <- 1
  p <- function(x,x0) x0^2
  while(i <= k){
    p = function(x,x0){ p(x,x0) + (x - x0)**i }
    i = i + 1
  }
  return(p(x,x0))
}
cum_f(x,1,5)
cum_f(10,1,5)
```

Comment: Please provide the formula you are trying to implement.

Comment: Part of the problem might be that there are two functions p, with one calling the function p itself. Try giving the second function p a different name.

Comment: Yep, I think @CalvinWhealton is right. In `p = function(x,x0){ p(x,x0) + (x - x0)**i }`, I guess `R` already views the new `p` as existing and therefore infinitely inserts new functions.

Comment: Well, but this work with numbers, so why not with functions. Python can deal with functions: see http://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.fr/2015/03/taylor-series-with-python-and-sympy.html and especially the following lines def taylor(function,x0,n):
    i = 0
    p = 0
    while i <= n:
        p = p + (function.diff(x,i).subs(x,x0))/(factorial(i))*(x-x0)**i
        i += 1
    return p

Comment: To Roland: I am trying to obtain p(x,x0) = x^2 + (x - x0) + (x - x0)**2 + (x - x0)**3 +...+ (x - x0)**k

Comment: Hi @Bertrand if my answer below helped you, please consider accepting it as an answer (check mark to  the left). This lets the community know the answer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need recursion? Is this what you're looking to do?

```
cum_f <- function(x, x0, k){
              i <- 1
              p <- x0**2
              while(i <= k){
                   p <- p + (x - x0)**i
                   i = i + 1
              }
              return(p)
         }

 cum_f(10,1,5) 

 # 66430
```

#### Alternative

You can get the same result with this function

```
cum_f <- function(x, x0, k){
             val <- Reduce("+", c(x0**2, (x-x0)**(1:k)), accumulate=TRUE)
             return(tail(val,1))
         }
```

Or even simpler (thanks Roland)

```
cum_f <- function(x, x0, k){
             val <- x0^2 + sum((x-x0)^(1:k))
             return(val)
         }

cum_f(10,1,5) 
# 66430
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Yes, it now returns the value of the function. I also wanted to obtain the whole function p something like p(x,x0) = x^2 + (x - x0) + (x - x0)**2 + (x - x0)**3 +...+ (x - x0)**k, but I can already do quite a few things with the values p(x,x0).

Comment: Why not simply `x0^2 + sum((x-x0)^(1:k))`? Btw., I'm not sure if OP wants `x^2` or `x0^2`.

Comment: @Roland, I have no idea what OP wants either